# Some bars don't reorder in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(commodity = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D"), 
          cost = c(1809065, 348456, 203686, 5966690, 172805, 3176424))
data
  commodity    cost
1         A 1809065
2         A  348456
3         B  203686
4         C 5966690
5         C  172805
6         D 3176424
```

Next I plot a barplot with `reorder`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(factor(commodity), cost), y = cost)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue3")
```

What happens next is that most bars are ordered just like I want, but a few aren't. Here's an image of my problematic plot:

[image]

Comment: try `reorder(commodity, cost, sum)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(commodity, cost, sum), y = cost)) +
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue3")
```

[image]

Change the default `mean` function of `reorder` to `sum`. Then the order is in line with the bar function of ggplot. Of note, using `geom_col` is prefered over `geom_bar` when using `stat="identity"`. If you need a decreased ordering try `rev(reorder(commodity, cost, sum))` or create a function by yourself like `function(x) -sum(x)`.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it works. Unfortunately I get another problem, there are very small differences in the spaces between the bars. I.e. some spaces are like 0.01 mm different than others. I should probably start another question for this, but wondered whether you've had experience with that using this very same framework as in this question.

Comment: Play with the `width` parameter in `geom_col`. Or try other resolutions. Hard to give a solution without seeing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reorder will by default reorder by the mean value for each group, as explained in the [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reorder.factor.html). Jimbou's solution is better but you could also do this in a different way by aggregating the data before plotting and using `geom_col` instead:

```
data %>%
  group_by(commodity) %>%
  summarise(cost = sum(cost)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(factor(commodity), cost), y = cost)) +
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue3")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Axeman: this is why I love SO as I learn new things. Edits made, but agree that the other solution is better.